# Hadoop cluster JAVA_HOME path not found with Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, java-home, path-variables

We have an Hadoop Cluster 2.3 where the JAVA_HOME is set to:

```
(cluster etc/profile)
$ echo $JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm
```

Running an Oozie Check form Ambari results in "everything OK" but when running any oozie command we get an error, e.g. :

```
$ oozie version
$ /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/oozie/bin/oozie.distro: line 59: /usr/lib/jvm/bin/java: 
No such file or directory
```

That happens probably because the code inside the script /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/oozie/bin/oozie.distro tries to calculate and use a JAVA_BIN path using:

```
...    
JAVA_BIN=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java  
...
```

Which does not exist!

The JAVA_HOME in our Hortonworks sandbox is set very differently, and there oozie works just fine:

```
(sandbox - cannot see any JAVA_HOME set into etc/profile)
$ echo $JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

Is it safe to change the JAVA_HOME of our cluster to point at the right location or that could influence other functionalities in the cluster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem. JAVA_HOME should always point to the root directory of JDK. Which in this case is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64` rather than `/usr/lib/jvm`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed default jdk by command

```
> sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

then, you should set JAVA_HOME as

```
> $JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-version
```

because this path is taken by default and you need to update at   **/.bashrc** file too.